# MongoDB Majority Read Concern

Tags: mongodb

I am working on mongoDB version 4.2

I need to cahnge the read concern from majority to local.

Accroding to the documentation the only way to do that for this version and lower versions is to change the configuration file by setting replication.enableMajorityReadConcern to false.

However, I did not find any indication on how to do that.
Tried:

```
replication:
  replSetName: rs0
  replication.enableMajorityReadConcern: false
```

and

```
replication:
  replSetName: rs0
  replication.enableMajorityReadConcern = false
```

but both fails.

What is the correct way to do this then?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
replication:
  replSetName: rs0
  enableMajorityReadConcern: false
```

Note, this parameter has been removed in MongoDB version 5.0. see [enableMajorityReadConcern Is Not Configurable](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/5.0/#enablemajorityreadconcern-is-not-configurable)

The long-term solution might be [Mitigate Performance Issues with PSA Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/mitigate-psa-performance-issues/)

Answer (score 0):

You can supply a value in your connection string.  For example:

```
mongodb://db0.example.com,db1.example.com,db2.example.com/?replicaSet=myRepl&readConcernLevel=local
```

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/ and look for `readConcern Options`

**GLobal Settings**

If you are seeking global settings, see `setDefaultRWConcern` at:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setDefaultRWConcern/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.setDefaultRWConcern